# Formula to determine total possible combinations of a set of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently using solver to look for combinations of numbers in a column to add up to a target number. Probably a task many of you are familiar with. What I would like to add to this sheet is a formula that show's how many possible combinations there are for solver to check as a way of showing how long someone can expect to wait for solver to finish going through the numbers. Obviously the number of combinations increases exponentially with each additional value but it would be nice to have a better visual.

Thank you

Comment: There are known calculations for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Comment: Also (eg): https://www.slideshare.net/sandradnicks/using-excel-to-calculate-permutations-and-combination-formulas